# Something strange with string ToDouble conversion

Tags: c#, double

I have `555 555 555` in `Box.Text`  (I have trimmed that value) 
then I call

```
double result = Convert.ToDouble(Box.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and my result is

```
555 555 584
```

WHY???  I have been waiting for the same 555 555 555 
Really strange bug, or I have missed something??

I have found the solution 555 555 584 is maximum value pre difined before.
The question is closed

Comment: Dunno, I can't reproduce with the information given. If I run the same `Convert.ToDouble` against `"555555555"` (as you said you trimmed it) i get `555555555.0`

Comment: sorry.. but that is really happens for me.

Comment: This code produces in an exception `Convert.ToDouble("555 555 555", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` Could you add the code used to print out that value?

Comment: @Steve he said he trimmed the value.

Comment: Set a breakpoint, and check what's the real value in your Box.Text. Or declare a string just before and assign Box.Text to it and output the value.

Comment: @curiousity you can verify yourself in a simple console application.  The problem must be elsewhere (i.e. the value isnt what you think, or something)

Answer (score 0):

Something is missing from your question.  Your input string cannot have spaces and your output of a double containing spaces is not possible.

```
double result = Convert.ToDouble("555 555 584", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Results in:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Try this:

```
string value = Box.Text.Replace(" ", "");
double result = Convert.ToDouble(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: By "(I have trimmed that value)" I guess he means he removed the spaces.

Comment: The parameter input of Box.Text is most likely the original raw text then ... "untrimmed" ... even though trimming is defined as removal of leading and/or trailing spaces ... not elimination of all spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You also can try this:

```
double result2 = Double.Parse("555555555");
```

P.S. Replace "555555555" with Box.Text